# Clean up Conda/Jupyter error messages accumulated cruft

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

I have a bunch of accumulated cruft I'd like to clean up.. any help appreciated!
When I start Jupyter Notebook I get:

```
server_extensions is deprecated, use nbserver_extensions
```

It seems I have nbserver extensions, How to get rid of the extraneous message? Is there a config file I can modify?

Further: When clicking on the "conda" tab I get an error on the tab it displays:

```
An error occurred while retrieving package information.
Not Found
```

and no packages or env's are displayed
And the terminal shows

```
[W 14:46:41.354 NotebookApp] 404 GET /conda/environments?_=1518813972634 (127.0.0.1) 8.62ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree/Documents
[W 14:46:41.356 NotebookApp] 404 GET /conda/packages/available?_=1518813972635 (127.0.0.1) 1.69ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree/Documents
```

Yet when I go to "change kernels" on the Notebook tab, all proper kernels display. Similarly if I use Anaconda-navigator, all my environments show up. 
I have updated Anaconda to 5.1 on Linux 16.04
when I run:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
python3    /home/tom/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
tf4        /home/tom/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/tf4
clojure    /home/tom/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/clojure
groovy     /home/tom/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/groovy
java       /home/tom/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/java
kotlin     /home/tom/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/kotlin
scala      /home/tom/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/scala
sql        /home/tom/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/sql
xonsh      /home/tom/anaconda3/share/jupyter/kernels/xonsh
```

The above entries are not my main kernels.. the two 1st entries are ones I created for Nteract using the Ipython kernels command.

I did experiance errors initially updating notebook on its own (pre the Anaconda update to 5.1) and got some help from the package maintainer but lost the entries on the conda tab

When running a basic notebook I get the following further errors yet thinks seem to run ok but I'd like to get stuff cleaned up:

```
[W 15:04:30.580 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/nbbrowserpdf/index.js?v=20180216144612 (127.0.0.1) 1.52ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Documents/InfluenceH/Working_copies/CCS_propensity_wking/Model_eval.ipynb
[I 15:04:30.679 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 465c992c-a8a0-4488-8d1d-8cf3b183e9f0
[W 15:04:30.702 NotebookApp] 404 GET /nbextensions/widgets/notebook/js/extension.js?v=20180216144612 (127.0.0.1) 1.22ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Documents/InfluenceH/Working_copies/CCS_propensity_wking/Model_eval.ipynb
```

Under the anaconda3 directory my env's are:

```
/home/tom/anaconda3/envs/py27
/home/tom/anaconda3/envs/py36
/home/tom/anaconda3/envs/py362
/home/tom/anaconda3/envs/py36j
/home/tom/anaconda3/envs/py36n
/home/tom/anaconda3/envs/pyfolioenv
/home/tom/anaconda3/envs/tf3rc
/home/tom/anaconda3/envs/tf4
/home/tom/anaconda3/envs/tf4n
```

There is a txt file under .conda that has more env's listed (some of which I had removed.)

So I guess some config file is missing and or misconfigured, any suggestion how to resolve?

Comment: Do you have the `server_extensions` package installed? Either by pip or by conda in whatever environment is running the Notebook? Similarly, do you have the [`nb_conda`](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda) package installed for the conda tab?

Comment: nb_conda reports itself as installed but  conda install server_extensions
Fetching package metadata ...............

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:
            
  - server_extensions

Comment: Right, sorry, I'm suggesting to remove the `server_extensions` package (if installed), since it has been replaced according to that warning...

Comment: server_extensions not installed